# The Desktop wouldn't appear after my recent update to 13.04

Tags: 13.04, nvidia

I have a hp 8570w workstation with an Nvidia graphics card. 
I did not update my system for a long time fearing that the graphics card would break and by mistake i updated the system recently. As expected it happen, my laptop gets stuck in blank screen when I power on. I am only able to login through tty1 to tty6 and on tty7 it just shows a blank screen and wouldn't proceed to the desktop. 
Can someone help me fix this problem ? 
Thank you

Comment: When you say "blank screen", do you mean the screen is black or does it manage to load your desktop image? And are you able to bring up a terminal windo (ctrl-alt-T) on tty7?

Comment: When I say blank screen i mean a screen with a char cursor on left top corner with nothing else on the screen for ever. And to get tty0-7 I type (Alt+F1 to F7).